# apt-update gives publickey error on NVIDIA docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nvidia

I'm asking a new question because stack overflow won't let me add a comment as I just joined, but I have a follow up to these threads:

[apt-update in Azure Nvidia gives publickey error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72051754/apt-update-in-azure-nvidia-gives-publickey-error)

https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1631

could someone please share a base image I could pull that has cuda, wget and Ubuntu18.04 installed - I have a dockerfile that works on AWS that I cannot edit that I need to run the following on first:

```
FROM base_image_needed
...
RUN apt-key del ...

RUN wget https_nvidia_cuda_keyring_pkg
```

the nvidia ubuntu images I have tried don't have wget installed:

https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags?page=1

thank you

Comment: the solution provided by gwenzek here worked for me:

https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1631

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this image which has Ubuntu 18.04 and cuda : [image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/nvidia/cuda/11.0-devel-ubuntu18.04-rc/images/sha256-3f5d21af43027e9e883e15e9019ca59cb8a2f1965b82b22de3252ed05f0c1af9?context=explore).
Regarding wget once you connet to image you should run `sudo apt-get install wget` that should help in fixing gpg keys issue.

Comment: thank you for replying @eyshika - I cannot run `apt-get` because of the NVIDIA issue in the link in the question, which is why I need an image that has cuda, Ubuntu and wget!